# Why doesn't Mathematica evaluate FourierTransform[Exp[-t], t, w]?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am having trouble getting Mathematica to evaluate a trivial Fourier transform.

I would like to be able to evaluate the Fourier transform of the right-sided exponential decay function as shown below. (The real proof is explored here:   [fourier.eng.hmc.edu](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node3.html))

$\qquad \mathscr{F}[e^{- t }u(t)] = \frac{1}{1 + j \omega} $

Once I have evaulated the Fourier transform I would like to plot it for $\omega = {1,5}$

I have tried the following:

```
FourierTransform[Exp[-t], t, w]
Table[%, {w, 5}]
ListLinePlot[Abs[%]]
```

The output from `FourierTransform` is my input with some formatting.

My attempt to create the table doesn't work...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: By using {w,5}, you set w to 1,2,3,4,5. If you want w only be 1 and 5, use {w,{1,5}}

Comment: Documentation Center > FourierTransform > Details and Options first bullet items explains the Fourier integral is taken from -infinity to infinity. Which in turn should explain both what was incorrect, and why the approach of @bills makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably what you want is:

```
ft[w_] = FourierTransform[UnitStep[t] Exp[-t], t, w]
```

Otherwise, for t negative, the integral diverges. Also, you might want to check out the option `FourierParameters`. To plot:

```
Plot[Abs[ft[w]], {w, 0, 10}]
```